# Cannot access Azure Artifacts Settings to remove inheritance

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I screwed up my Feed settings trying to do cross-project pushes.  I think I know how to fix it, but I can't seem to get to a setting that I had changed in order to change it back.  Long story short, I have inherited permissions that are blocking me, but I can't ge to the screen to un-set it:
[image]

Now these are set in a right side slide-out that has the option:

> Only administrators and these users can create feeds

Which I believe is in **Azure Artifacts settings** according to all the documentation, but for the life of me I can't seem to find it again.  Can someone please help me un-set this!

Comment: @Dave M changemy question so it is no longer at all what I asked.  I cannot FIND the settings - as in I cannot get to the settings.  Thanks for beinh unhelpful question police and making my question less clear.

Comment: I am not sure how removing thanks and "Maybe I am just being dumb" from the post changed the question in a meaningful way.  Please note that there was an earlier edit as well as mine.

Comment: You changed the title, I changed it back

Comment: Sorry.  Wasn't me that changed title.  That was an earlier edit.